# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 and will not connect to the internet. Help!

Tags: 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop which had a pirate copy of windows xp and would not let me log in because I was unable to authenticate. It in most ways appeared to install correctly, The screen shows everything etc. However, even when hooked up by ethernet it will not let me access the internet, and it does not show any of the wi-fi available. I wonder if I should not have chosen the selection that erased everything else and installed...or...? I dont know. Someone once said something about saving drivers? In any case, dont want to throw my laptop away just because windows locked me out. Can a non-cmomputer savy person such as myself actually use Ubuntu or am I SOL?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have choosen option that erased everything, that doesnt affect your network connectivity, also windows drivers dont work in linux so you wouldn't need them anyway. Now for your network connectivity, first open terminal(press Windows(Super) key and type terminal) and then post output of `sudo ifconfig`.